# Is it possible to give a textarea spell checking in a specified language?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a flash cards app for language learning, and I have `spellcheck="false"` set on my input for the foreign language. Ideally I would be able to spell check that input in the target language, is this possible (without making a custom text editor)?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang

> Even if the lang attribute is set, it may not be taken into account, as the xml:lang attribute has priority.

But this minimal test doen't work on Chrome ...

```html
<html><body>
    <textarea spellcheck="true" lang="en-GB">Thiss is a test mesage.</textarea>
    <textarea spellcheck="true" lang="fr-FR">Un mesage puor test.</textarea>
</body></html>
```